# Git merge and history change

Tags: git, github, merge, rebase

These are our current branches:

- master
- staging
- feature

now `feature` was born from staging, and had many commits along the way with some merging from staging and master.

But when `feature` was born from staging. staging had several commits that were later removed...

ie:

```
staging: a->b->c->d->e
feature: a->b->c->d->e->f->h->i->j...
```

but after some time, somebody removed commits from staging history
so now this is the status

```
staging: c->d->e
feature: a->b->c->d->e->f->h->i->j...
```

but make things worse, there were more commits to staging that later got merged to feature

```
staging: c->d->e->s1->s2->s3
feature: a->b->c->d->e->f->h->i->j->s1->s2->s3->f1->f2
```

any ideas how I can get the diff in commits from `feature` to `staging` ?

cause when I run

```
git show-branch feature staging
```

I get nothing, cause staging was merged to feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git log staging..feature
git log staging...feature
```

See the docs at https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html for explanation of `..` and `...` syntax.

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#gitrevisions-Theememtwo-dotRangeNotation

Answer (score 0):

If you're in the feature branch, you can do

```
git diff feature staging
```

This would show you all the difference from the feature to staging. You can also do this to your master branch as well.

However if you would like a more Visual way to see the difference, I recommend using SourceTree or IntelliJ IDE applications to get a better visual vs the terminal.

You can also do `git log` in your feature branch if you want to see a list of previous commits.

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm unsure of what you are asking, are you trying to revert the merge? Or get a list of history of commits?

Comment: I would like to get the list of commit I have on `feature` but not on `staging`

Comment: So the staging branch is currently gone because you had already merged that into your feature branch? Is that correct?

Comment: what do you mean gone? it still exists... but it was merged into feature after its history was changed... so now I have old commits from staging who are not on staging anymore. so I just want to get that list